find area of part of surface $z=2-x^2+y$ that lies above triangle in xy-plane with vertices $(0,-1),(1,0) , (0,1)$
$$A = \int_{x=-1}^{1} \int_{y=-x-1}^{x-1} \sqrt{2 + 4x^2} \, dy \, dx$$
$$A = \int_{x=-1}^{1} 2x \sqrt{2 + 4x^2} \, dx$$
$$
A = \frac{1}{6} \ [[{2+4x^2}]^{3/2}]
$$
$$
A = \frac{1}{6} \left[ 6^{3/2} - 6^{3/2} \right]
$$
I keep getting $0$ as the value of this integral. The answer is supposed to be $A = \frac{3\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{3}$. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

How can we answer if you don't tell us how you got $0$?

Isn't $0\leq x\leq1$?

@SineoftheTime From $\sqrt{1 + {(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})}^2 + {(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})}^2}$.

@JohnBarber Ah, I see. I misinterpreted the question

Your bounds of integration are wrong (I believe you've flipped $x$ and $y$ when trying to construct the bounds). If you draw out the triangle on the coordinate plane, you can integrate from $x=0$ to $1$, then $y=x-1$ to $1-x$. So we have
\begin{align*}
A&=\int_0^1\int_{x-1}^{1-x}\sqrt{2+4x^2}dydx\\
&=\int_0^1 (2-2x)\sqrt{2+4x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}+\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt{2}),
\end{align*}
which does not appear to be the value listed on the answer key.
However, if we set the triangle to be at vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,-1)$, we can integrate from $x=0$ to $1$ and $y=-x$ to $x$, which gives the answer $\frac{3\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{3}$.

Shouldn't it be $x-1 \le y \le 1-x$?

@SineoftheTime You're right, I've edited my answer (though now it appears to not match with the answer key answer they've given).

The coordinates in my textbook might be wrong. Thank you for correcting it!
